# Processing time for German job seeker visa

Tags: visa, germany, job-hunting

I am applying for German job seeker visa at New York center on 1st week of December and I am planning to travel overseas towards the end of December. I need help to know what is the processing time for job seeker visa and how much time they will take for stamping.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Visa : Frequently Asked Questions - Federal Foreign Office](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/faq-visa/899734) the general answer is:

> **How long will I have to wait for my visa?**
>   The processing time for visa applications (**short stay**) takes up to 15 days.
>
> If **long-term** residence permits or visa for employment in Germany are applied for, the processing time will be up to several months.

As a general rule, visas where consultation with the **Aliens' Authority (Ausländerbehörde)** are needed take longer.

When this is meantioned at the [Visa for Germany](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/aamt/zugastimaa/buergerservice/faq/-/606848?openAccordionId=item-606742-27-panel) or [Employment in Germany](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/employment-visa/922292)

- as it is for the **student visa** in the first site
- or [Jobseeker](https://www.germany.info/blob/942162/93fd52958d9775a4904969afbf4fe3f2/jobseeker-data.pdf) (the pdf form you will need to fill out) in the second

assume the time needed will be longer (1 to 3 months).